# How can a HTML DOM element be passed from a background script to content script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

How can I pass an array of HTML DOM elements from background script to content script as the chrome extension [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) states " A message can contain any valid JSON object (null, boolean, number, string, array, or object)".

Possible way - (Tried, but couldn't create the object again successfully)

- Converting HTML DOM element to htmlString, passing the message and creating the DOM element again in content script.

Comment: You can't pass elements. Your idea of using HTML string is a correct workaround. To rebuild the elements either assign to innerHTML of any DOM element or use DOMParser API.

Comment: _"Tried, but couldn't create the object again"_ show that attempt. You would have needed to parse the passed string back by using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), or inserting into a container element with [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)